# Selecting top N elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

Assuming we have such a structure (the number of `b` in every `a` is unknown):

```
<a>
    <b/>
    <b/>
    <b/>
</a>
<a>
    <b/>
    <b/>
    <b/>
</a>
```

How would we express the following phrase in xpath: "top 4 b elements nested into a"

The `a/b[position() <= 4]` for obvious reasons returns all 6 elements.

How would I limit it to 4?

I've found that `(a/b)[position() <= 4]` should work, but seems it's `xpath 2.0`. Any ideas for `1.0` version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you say

> (a/b)[position() <= 4] should work, but **seems it's xpath 2.0**

? That's perfectly legitimate XPath 1.0, and in fact is a common idiom for this purpose. I just tested it to confirm that it's accepted and works correctly.

It may also be more efficient than using `count(preceding::b)`, depending on the XPath processor.

Comment: Well, I tried it with PHP DOM XPath, and it says the expression is wrong. So as soon as it only supports 1.0, I assumed that syntax isn't 1.0

Comment: Checked it now once again, and now it works. Feeling stupid :-S

Answer (score 4):

Not pretty, but this checks how many `<b>`s there are earlier in the document.

```
a/b[count(preceding::b) < 4]
```

It's not perfect. If there are other `<b>`s not inside of `<a>`s it'll fail. For example:

```
<b>oops</b>
<a>
    <b/>
    <b/>
    <b/>
</a>
<a>
    <b/>
    <b/>
    <b/>
</a>
```

This one doesn't get tripped up by the `<b>oops</b>` element.

```
a/b[count(preceding::b/parent::a) < 4]
```